# Is there a command to refresh environment variables from the Bash Terminal (Git bash) in Windows?

Tags: bash, terminal, cygwin, mingw, git-bash

##### The problem

I use Git Bash which is based on [MinGW](https://www.mingw-w64.org/).
Around the day I often change the Windows PATH environment variable, in it are the paths to my tools, such as PHP, for example.

I use tools to change PHP versions, this tool automatically changes the PHP environment variable to a different version.

**I would like to have a command that from the bash terminal itself I can run it and refresh the environment variables.**

##### What have I tried?

I have tried almost everything in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171588/is-there-a-command-to-refresh-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt-in-w) without any success. The only thing that has worked for me is to run a new terminal with administrator privileges, but I would not want to have this as the best option.

I tried:

- [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/171737/13522473)
- [#5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9016150/13522473)
- [#7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11955920/13522473)
- [Restart explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22027353/13522473)
- [Chocolatey alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32420542/13522473)
- [An alternative to the Chocolatey command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69408975/13522473)  that is supposed to be compatible with Bash. Here is a [github issue](https://github.com/badrelmers/RefrEnv/issues/1), has a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEYLydC-ElM) that might help you understand what I want to do

I guess none of the above worked for me because they were not made for git bash, that's why I created this question.
I have also tried all of the above with a terminal like [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) which is similar to Git Bash, without success.

I've come close to achieving this with this command, but I can't get it to work.

```
export PATH="$(cygpath -pu "`{ reg query 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment' /v PATH | grep PATH | cut -c23- ; reg query 'HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' /v PATH | grep PATH | cut -c30-; } | tr "\n" " "`")"
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve with the above command is to take the PATH environment variables out of the registry and put them in export PATH to update bash. But first I have to concatenate the system variables and the user variables. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9402228/13522473) for more info.

Comment: I always avoid touching the system PATH in Windows. Instead I make changes to PATH inside the shell itself. This allows mo to have different instances of the bash shell doing different things (e.g. using different compiler versions).

Comment: Hi @BrechtSanders, can you give me an example of this?

Comment: For example (in bash): `export PATH=D:/Perl/bin:$PATH` Make sure to avoid spaces and backslashes

Comment: I use scripts (which I source) which add tool-chain version dependent folders to paths like variables, including PATH and also sets any dependent environment variables. My default setup has no tool-chain specialization. I can start multiple terminal windows or mintty windows, and customize each window by sourcing different scripts so I can test my code with multiple tool-chain versions. This technique works for cmd or terminal windows (using batch scripts) and for cygwin, mingw, git bash, and linux (using bash scripts). This is a safe and reliable method for setting up isolated setups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a [custom script](https://github.com/badrelmers/RefrEnv/blob/main/refrenv.sh) created by
[Badr Elmers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3020379/badr-elmers) Works just as I expected and works in Git Bash, Cygwin.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69408975/13522473)